# Git find/restore a unknown deleted file in a known folder?

Tags: git, git-log

More then 100 commits ago I deleted a file in a folder. The folder I know but not the deleted filename. How can I get the deleted filenames only in this folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest doing

```
git log --name-only --pretty="" --diff-filter=D -- your/folder | sort -u
```

where
`--name-only` outputs file names
`--pretty=""` suppresses standard commit info output
`--diff-filter=D` filters commits (only deletions)
`| sort -u` sorts and gets rid of doubles

Comment: Not seeing the use of the `sort -u`, is any given path going to be deleted more than once?

Comment: @jthill I'll happily grant you it's uncommon, but it could happen that a file is deleted and recreated. And if not, nothing breaks anyway.